# How to script Catalina Security & Privacy Preferences

Tags: macos, security, catalina, script, privacy

In my line of work we use LanRev for our remote management.  However, with new machines using Catalina, we've had to manually allow Full Disc Access in order for remote control to work.

Is there way to use a script to apply this setting instead of having to manually apply it?